# Typescript not inferring property on extends

Tags: typescript

I ran into some trouble with TS compiler complaining that a string literal did not satisfy a string literal union type that should have the string.

```
type Payload = {
    data: {
        id: string;
        hi: {
            id: string;
        };
    }
}

type Filter<T extends Payload> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { id: any } | undefined | null ? K : never;
};
type HasId<T extends Payload> = Filter<T>[keyof T];

const genericVersion = <T extends Payload> (something: T): HasId<T> => {
    return 'data'; // error here
}

const staticVersion = <T extends Payload> (t: T): HasId<Payload> => {
    return 'data';
}

const main = () => {
    let d = genericVersion({ data: { id: '', hi: { id: '' } } });
}
```

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEygXigbwFBSFRpzBwBcuBRNAlmpQM7ABOtAdgOYDc1NhAC1qV8-MVHpNWHHn34BfXjXl4VeUJCgAxWomAQWAHgAqUCAA997NI1gIU6AHxYqNANoBpCeygBrCCDIAGZQxgC6lMaeYWaWENa2OBIMUHDsIFDyUAA+UACu1hBBHBAYuex5iIhQAPxQXpTsEABuBryK6uDQABJwjACSaCaxVjZ2SKhoztg6egYmjm7+gSHhvHgAxsjszFCc8Qa0GwBqBoy02y7DFqO28BNOUAAUjMgAthDAQlyRAJSUvQGQ2M02coiILE+eRYPgA5CQyLD2nhNttdsxSEdTixzpdsNc4glxg4ps9gH8AX1BoZ7iTQa4IVCYVB4aQ4EjVCitjtgFA3nAOC4nr8sGC5IhPsQXPsmmwTmcLuwnkkERRcMlKLDYQAaKBCEQalmwzIm+S-dpAA)

I'm expecting no error for either of the functions.

Comment: So, you want `genericVersion({ data: { id: '', hi: { id: '' } }, blob: null })` to have return type `"data" | "blob"`?  I'm confused about what you're doing and why you don't just make the return type `"data"`.  The reason there's an error is that the compiler doesn't perform the kind of sophisticated type analysis to see that `"data"` is always assignable to `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { id: any } | undefined | null ? K : never}[keyof T]` when `T extends Payload` (hard for me too ).If you want this you might have to help it out (e.g., return `"data" | HasId<T>` which should be the same).

Comment: Regarding the `'data' | 'blob'`; yes, I would, since I'm just documenting a JS function, not writing new JS code, and I would like it to be maximally permissive up to the point where it's still correct.

I think that Typescript not being able to infer this feels like a bug. :( Well, I'll have to help it out for now, then. Thanks!